# how to create re-usable field component in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I have 2-3 fields that is reused is other forms of my application. So i wanted to create those fields as component so that I can resuse is my other forms. but redux-form is complaining that

```
Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()
```

Any ideas how can I achieve it? BTW, I am using material-ui

EDIT: providing a better e.g. consider the material-ui toolbar

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toolbar

My toolbar consists of a selectField, textField, Toggle button, which may couple of forms. In my app, I want to keep this toolbar in all the forms where I create objects in my application, so I want to include this toolbar in all the forms. After the below answer I tried something dirty like below.

```
class BaseBar extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 3,
            isGlueOpen: false,
        };
    }

    handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.setState({value: value});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Toolbar>
              <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
                  <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                      <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="All Broadcasts" />
                      <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="All Voice" />
                      <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="All Text" />
                      <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Complete Voice" />
                      <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Complete Text" />
                      <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Active Voice" />
                      <MenuItem value={7} primaryText="Active Text" />
                  </DropDownMenu>
              </ToolbarGroup>
              <ToolbarSeparator />
              <ToolbarGroup>
                  <ToggleButton onChange={this.props.glueToggle}/>
              </ToolbarGroup>
          </Toolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default BaseBar;
```

and including the form like below

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
              <Field
                  name="basebar"
                  component={BaseBar}
                  label="project"
              />
          </div>
          <div>
              <Field
                  name="subject"
                  component={renderTextField}
                  label="subject"
              />
          </div>
   </form>
```

But on submit, I am getting the values for subject field but not the basebar values, any suggestions or approach is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your current code

Comment: [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480120) may help you.

Comment: I think I should consider using FormSection, I somehow missed to see that..

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you're trying to use the Field outside the context of a connected Redux Form.

Perhaps you could create your shareable component without the `<Field>` component itself, and then use that component in as many forms as you need, wrapping it with `Field`. See example usage in the documentation:

http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/Field.md/#usage

```
import MyCustomInput from './MyCustomInput'

...

<Field name="myField" component={MyCustomInput}/>
```

Where `MyCustomInput` is your custom, common component.

Or if you have custom logic to map Field props to your components, then use a function which you can then export and reuse in as many forms as you need.

```
// this is your custom component now
export const renderMyCustomField = (field) => (
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...field.input} type="text"/>
      {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && 
       <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  )
...
//which you can then import in your forms
import { renderMyCustomField } from '...'

// inside your render() method
<Field name="myField" component={renderMyCustomField}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to reusable redux form field component :)
Here my elegant soloution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { string, object } from 'prop-types';
import { Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';

const Input = ({
  input,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      {...input}
      {...rest}
    />
    {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
  </div>
);

Input.propTypes = {
  input: object.isRequired,
  meta: object.isRequired,
  type: string.isRequired
};

Input.defaultProps = {
  input: null,
  meta: null,
  type: 'text'
};

export default props => <Field {...props} component={Input} />;
```

How to use?

```
import Input from './Input';

<form>
...

<Input
  autoComplete="off"
  name="email"
  placeholder="Email"
  type="email"
/>
...
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, what would be your solution if I have form with a sub form of tabs and each tabs has different forms which the user may or may not fill in?